# calling windows form from console in C#

Tags: c#

I'm using C# .net 4.0 VS 2010.

I copied the following code here in Stackoverflow and confirmed all from the reference that this is suppose to work, but i am having syntax error on my call on the "Application.Run(new ShoutBox());" the error is "The type or namespace 'ShoutBox' could not be found."

The project was originally build as a console application. I just recently added a windows form named ShoutBox and is saved as ShoutBox.cs. I have transfer my code to the form so it does not display stuff in console rather on a textbox of the windows form i created.

What did i missed? And how can i make it work?

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace ChatApp
    {
        class ConsoleApplication1
        {


            [STAThread]
            static void Main()
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();


                //this one works
                Application.Run(new Form()); // or whatever


                //this one does not work, error on second ShoutBox
                Form ShoutBox = new Form();
                Application.Run(new ShoutBox()); 
            }


        }
    }
```

Just for reference, here is my final working code:
This code creates a new Shoutbox form instead of a blanked form.

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using ShoutBox; // Adding this

    namespace ChatApp
    {
        class ConsoleApplication1
        {        
            [STAThread]
            static void Main()
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Form ShoutBox1 = new ShoutBox.ShoutBox(); //Changing this
                Application.Run(ShoutBox1);               //Changing this
            }
        }
    }
```

where my Shoutbox form are as follows:

```
    using System
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    namespace ShoutBox
    {
        public partial class ShoutBox : Form
        {
    ....
```

Comment: This is a simple compilation error. Search for "The type or namespace could not be found." You're either missing a Reference (is the ShoutBox class in a different Project?) and/or missing a using (is the ShoutBox class in a different Namespace?) and/or it does not exist (is the ShoutBox class defined anywhere?) - there are many answers that cover this and it has *nothing* inherently to do with Forms. Quite simply: the code in question *cannot resolve the ShoutBox type*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ShoutBox` is the name of a variable referencing a Form, you can't call new ShoutBox().

You have already instantiated the form in the previous line, now you call simply

```
 Application.Run(ShoutBox);
```

But, if you have a form called ShoutBox defined in this way

```
namespace ShoutBox
{
     public partial class ShoutBox: Form
     {
        .....
     }
}
```

then you need to add the using declaration at the beggining of your file

```
using ShoutBox;
```

or you can simply change the namespace used in the `ShoutBox.cs` file to the same namespace used in the program Main file

```
namespace ChatApp
{
     public partial class ShoutBox: Form
     {
        ....    
     }
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem. Thanks. I'll accept it as soon as I'm able.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing either one or two things.

Firstly, you need to import the namespace that `ShoutBox` is in:

```
using Your.Namespace.Where.ShoutBox.Is.Declared;
```

An easy way to do this in Visual Studio is to put your cursor somewhere on the word `ShoutBox` and either press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> or.. as some people who are much more productive than I am do, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. This will bring up a menu that will show the namespace that needs to be included.

Also, if that namespace is in another assembly (you alluded to that), then you need to add it as a reference to the project.

Also, this:

```
Form ShoutBox = new Form();
Application.Run(new ShoutBox());
```

..is incorrect. I would suggest a tutorial on basic class creation.

Answer (score 0):

The ShoutBox class is propably in different namespace.

And the code `Form ShoutBox = new Form();` is useless, you need only `Application.Run(new ShoutBox());`.